# GWT history iframe

Tags: gwt, iframe, history, gwt-history

I am using GWT and need history and using:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

But can I change `__gwt_historyFrame` to any other name `AAAAA`? Is it possible like below:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="AAAAA" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please stop creating a new account each time you come to this site and ask a moderator to combine your many existing accounts. http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+msaif

Answer (score 2):

Here is some good documentation on the GWT History: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=232
and Google's documentation on the host page: http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.Fundamentals.HostPage.html

Giving the following code example:

```
<!-- Include a history iframe to enable full GWT history support -->
<!-- (the id must be exactly as shown)                           -->
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

Sounds like the iframe must have id="__gwt_historyFrame" and cannot be changed to "AAAAA" or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build your own version of GWT with a custom implementation of HistoryImplFrame. And as other replies have stated, there really isn't a good reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the MVP architecture presented by Google, you won't need to change it in order to handle history. I don't see why you would want to change it but this look like a GWT Defined variable that you shouldn't change.

Comment: i dont open to the other programmer that i wrote entire thing in gwt.
for this reason i need to change.

Comment: I really don't understand what you just wrote, sorry.

Comment: if i use __gwt_historyFrame then anybody can rightclick on the document and can press view source then entire html source will be visible.then user can understand that i wrote the entire thing in gwt thats why i like to change

Comment: OK.... I don't understand why should that matter, but anyway this is your choice. In the end, sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: @msaif, security through obscurity is *never* a good idea. Don't try to hide the fact that you are using GWT - cause you won't succeed. See for example your project-name/project-name.nocache.js - there are many references to GWT there. PS: And for Chrits's sake, use one account.